# How does overlayfs determine what folders to merge and what folders to replace

Tags: linux, filesystems

How does `overlayfs` determine what folders to merge and what folders to replace?

```
Tree:
  -lower
    -dir1
      -file1
  -upper
  -work
  -ready
```

Mount command:

```sh
mount -t overlay -o lowerdir=lower,upperdir=upper,workdir=work overlayfs ready
```

Case 1(merge):

```sh
cd ready/dir1
echo "newFile">newFile
#New file placed at upper/dir1/newFile.
#Then remount overlayfs, and we see both files in ready dir
```

Case 2(replace):

```sh
cd ready
rm dir1 -Rf
mkdir dir1
cd dir1
echo "newFile">newFile
# newFile placed at upper dir also
# Unmount/Remount overlayfs and we see only newFile
```

Comment: I found some [info](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/filesystems/overlayfs.txt):
A directory is made opaque by setting the xattr "trusted.overlay.opaque"
to "y".  Where the upper filesystem contains an opaque directory, any
directory in the lower filesystem with the same name is ignored.

But `getfattr -d -R upper` prints empty attrs

Answer (score 1):

Merge or replace depends from "trusted.overlay.opaque" xattr

## Check xattr example

`getfattr -R -d -m "" upper/`

`# file: upper//ttt
trusted.overlay.opaque="y"`

## Remove "trusted.overlay.opaque"

use a command `setfattr --remove "trusted.overlay.opaque" upper/ttt` to remove this xattr